# Angular 10 Cannot Find @angular modules

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

I have just upgraded from Angular 9 to Angular 10. None of my typescript files seem to be able to find the node_modules folder. All my references to @angular are generating an "cannot find module error". For example import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'.

1. The project build 100% when I run ng build --prod
2. The errors on only generated when I open the files in the Visual Studio IDE
3. I can confirm the modules are present in the node_modules folder

I suspect that the problem lies in the IDE not being able to resolve the location of the module.

Any ideas
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried clearing npm cache `npm cache clean --force `?

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of these options:

1. Try remove your `node_modules` and run

> `npm install`

Or

2. Inside your `tsconfig.json` file add

> `"baseUrl": "src"`

If this couldn't help, you can read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

Comment: I think this answer is right. NGCC need to build a new Ivy version of all modules. Removing the node_modules folder will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the answer. The problem relates to the new solution files being used by Angular 10 which Visual Studio 2019 does not handle. The 2019 preview of VS has the fix, but it is not released yet. For those who need here are the links you can read more about this.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1095160/solution-style-tsconfigjson-not-loaded-correctly.html?childToView=1113710#comment-1113710

https://angular.io/guide/migration-solution-style-tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

Something has been obviously changed between Angular 9 to 10 in code related to imports, and baseUrl.
**The fix is to change baseUrl in tsconfig.json** as follows (note trailing slash character):

```
"baseUrl": "src/",
```